# OrientDB - Windows service error

Tags: orientdb

I am trying to install orientdb 2.2.6 as a service. It runs fine from the command line, however when installing as a service I get:

```
[2016-08-10 11:54:19] [debug] ( prunsrv.c:1679) [ 4724] Commons Daemon procrun log initialized
[2016-08-10 11:54:19] [info]  ( prunsrv.c:1683) [ 4724] Commons Daemon procrun (1.0.15.0 64-bit) started
[2016-08-10 11:54:19] [info]  ( prunsrv.c:1596) [ 4724] Running 'OrientDBServer' Service...
[2016-08-10 11:54:19] [debug] ( prunsrv.c:1374) [ 3564] Inside ServiceMain...
[2016-08-10 11:54:19] [debug] ( prunsrv.c:844 ) [ 3564] reportServiceStatusE: 2, 0, 3000, 0
[2016-08-10 11:54:19] [info]  ( prunsrv.c:1127) [ 3564] Starting service...
[2016-08-10 11:54:19] [debug] ( javajni.c:233 ) [ 3564] loading jvm 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101\bin\server\jvm.dll'
[2016-08-10 11:54:19] [debug] ( javajni.c:704 ) [ 8348] Jvm Option[0] -Djava.util.logging.config.file=D:\orientdb\orientdb-community-2.2.6/config/orientdb-server-log.properties
[2016-08-10 11:54:19] [debug] ( javajni.c:704 ) [ 8348] Jvm Option[1] -Dorientdb.config.file=D:\orientdb\orientdb-community-2.2.6/config/orientdb-server-config.xml
[2016-08-10 11:54:19] [debug] ( javajni.c:704 ) [ 8348] Jvm Option[2] -Dorientdb.www.path=D:\orientdb\orientdb-community-2.2.6/www
[2016-08-10 11:54:19] [debug] ( javajni.c:704 ) [ 8348] Jvm Option[3] -Dlog.console.level=info
[2016-08-10 11:54:19] [debug] ( javajni.c:704 ) [ 8348] Jvm Option[4] -Dlog.file.level=fine
[2016-08-10 11:54:19] [debug] ( javajni.c:704 ) [ 8348] Jvm Option[5] -Dorientdb.build.number=@BUILD@
[2016-08-10 11:54:19] [debug] ( javajni.c:704 ) [ 8348] Jvm Option[6] -DORIENTDB_HOME=D:\orientdb\orientdb-community-2.2.6
[2016-08-10 11:54:19] [debug] ( javajni.c:704 ) [ 8348] Jvm Option[7] -Djava.class.path=D:\orientdb\orientdb-community-2.2.6\lib\activation-1.1.jar;D:\orientdb\orientdb-community-2.2.6\lib\antlr-2.7.7.jar;D:\orientdb\orientdb-community-2.2.6\lib\asm-3.2.jar;D:\orientdb\orientdb-community-2.2.6\lib\asm-analysis-3.2.jar;D:\orientdb\orientdb-community-2.2.6\lib\asm-commons-3.2.jar;D:\orientdb\orientdb-community-2.2.6\lib\asm-tree-3.2.jar;D:\orientdb\orientdb-community-2.2.6\lib\asm-util-3.2.jar;D:\orientdb\orientdb-community-2.2.6\lib\blueprints-core-2.6.0.jar;D:\orientdb\orientdb-community-2.2.6\lib\commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar;D:\orientdb\orientdb-community-2.2.6\lib\commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar;D:\orientdb\orientdb-community-2.2.6\lib\commons-collections-3.2.2.jar;D:\orientdb\orientdb-community-2.2.6\lib\commons-configuration-1.6.jar;D:\orientdb\orientdb-community-2.2.6\lib\commons-digester-1.8.jar;D:\orientdb\orientdb-community-2.2.6\lib\commons-lang-2.4.jar;D:\orientdb\orientdb-community-2.2.6\lib\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;D:\orientdb\orientdb-community-2.2.6
[2016-08-10 11:54:19] [debug] ( javajni.c:704 ) [ 8348] Jvm Option[8] exit
[2016-08-10 11:54:19] [error] ( javajni.c:863 ) [ 8348] FindClass Main failed
[2016-08-10 11:54:19] [debug] ( javajni.c:964 ) [ 8348] Java Worker thread finished Main:main with status=3
[2016-08-10 11:54:19] [error] ( prunsrv.c:1183) [ 3564] Failed to start Java
[2016-08-10 11:54:19] [error] ( prunsrv.c:1536) [ 3564] ServiceStart returned 4
[2016-08-10 11:54:19] [debug] ( prunsrv.c:844 ) [ 3564] reportServiceStatusE: 1, 1066, 0, 4
[2016-08-10 11:54:19] [info]  ( prunsrv.c:1598) [ 4724] Run service finished.
[2016-08-10 11:54:19] [info]  ( prunsrv.c:1764) [ 4724] Commons Daemon procrun finished
```

I cannot see any filesystem errors when using procmon, and the java paths seem fine. An help appreciated.

Paul

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to setup it on Windows 10 using this [guide](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Windows-Service.html). The service is starting normally and I have no errors in log:

`[2016-08-10 14:27:52] [info]  [ 8272] Commons Daemon procrun (1.0.15.0 64-bit) started
[2016-08-10 14:27:52] [info]  [ 8272] Service OrientDBGraph name OrientDB GraphEd X.X.X
[2016-08-10 14:27:52] [info]  [ 8272] Service 'OrientDBGraph' installed
[2016-08-10 14:27:52] [info]  [ 8272] Commons Daemon procrun finished
[2016-08-10 14:30:16] [info]  [  500] Commons Daemon procrun (1.0.15.0 64-bit) started
[2016-08-10 14:30:16] [info]  [  500] Running 'OrientDBGraph' Service...
[2016-08-10 14:30:16] [info]  [ 8380] Starting service...
[2016-08-10 14:30:17] [info]  [ 8380] Service started in 1648 ms.`

Can you check the presence of `.jar` libraries in your `D:\orientdb\orientdb-community-2.2.6\lib\` folder, double check the `jvm.dll` and `ORIENTDB_HOME` paths or better make a fresh download of latest OrientDB version from the [official website](http://orientdb.com/download/) and try again.

Hope it helps, let me know.